# How do I close the browser console with code in the console

Tags: javascript, console, browser

I need to close the browser console like if I hit f12 but in code. The same as how in a comand prompt you would type exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No browser that I know of allows for the real console to be opened and closed via code.

That said, [Firebug Light](https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js) may offer the features that you need.